# Unblock a website with mysqladmin flush-host

Tags: mysql, flush

I'm using [Klipfolio](http://www.klipfolio.com) to access my MySQL database which is hosted on [InmotionHosting](http://www.inmotionhosting.com). But now, when I try to connect it gives me the error:

```
Unable to connect to database jdbc:mysql://www.website.com:3306/database: null, message from server: "Host '204.232.200.157' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'"
```

How do I unblock it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix this is contact inmotion support and ask them to clear the IP

Comment: Acutally, this didn't work. They had to do something else to fix it. After clearing the IP they realized it didn't work and then fixed it. But as before, they have to do it.